# Why does Round(-0.0066219357357) return -1?

Tags: delphi

I want to `Round(-0.0066219357357)` and it gives `-1`.

Isn't it supposed to be `0`? And what can I use to round it correctly?

**UPDATE:**
the number is a result of (LineDirection.X/distance);
where LineDirection.X is an integer and Distace is double.

Comment: I think it's strange. That would be `Ceil()`. `Round` has other "problems" (it uses banker's rounding)

Comment: Tested with a Delphi XE console application, no uses:   `Writeln(Round(-0.0066219357357));`
shows 0!

Comment: Different options set with `SetRoundMode` also give always 0.

Comment: Uhm. This is such an easy test case that I am tempted to say making errors is not an option. So what's different here? I'm @ D2009.

Comment: I use this code in XE (uses Math) giving all "0":`begin
  for rm := Low(TFPURoundingMode) to High(TFPURoundingMode) do begin
    SetRoundMode(rm);
    Writeln(Round(-0.0066219357357));
  end;
`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another Round function that is accidentally used? A line like this can give you problems: `function Round(e: Extended): Extended; begin Result := Trunc(e); end;`

Comment: If I put the value into an Extended I get (0, -1, 0, 0); The compiler seems to have a strange handling of float constants. Looks like Math.SetRoundMode is the solution.

Comment: Actually the number provided is the result of division of integer/double but when i show it in a watch window it appears as it's a double. so i wonder if the integer of the division is the cause of this

Comment: @Sara: The operator / always produces a floating point result, so both operands should be converted to Extended before the division is performed.

Comment: @UweRaabe: you got all zeroes first time because `Round` is one of functions allowed in [constant expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Constant_Expressions)

Comment: @Sara: Just created chat room for this question - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/4552/delphi-why-does-round-return-1 Join, and I will try to help you on-line.

Comment: Did you use the `/` operator or the `div` operator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking into System.pas from XE, all work is done by FISTP instruction:

```
    procedure _ROUND;
    asm
      ...
            FISTP   qword ptr [ESP]
      ...
    end;
```

According to the Intel's [Instruction Reference](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-2b-instruction-set-a-z-manual.html), value "is rounded to an integer value, according to the rounding mode specified by the RC field of the FPU control word"

So, I would advise you to check if this *RC* field of FPU control word is set to the rounding you need.

You can do this by working with whole *control word* - see [Set8087CW](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Set8087CW), and related `xxxx8087CW` procedures/functions, with [Default8087CW](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Default8087CW) variable.

Or you can try [Math.SetRoundMode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Math.SetRoundMode), as @Uwe Raabe suggested. Your case sounds like <strike>either rmUp or rmTruncate</strike> `rmDown` was used.

Theoretically, your CPU can be the reason as well, however, it hardly so.

Answer (score 6):

From the Delphi help:

> The behavior of Round can be affected by the Set8087CW procedure or [Math.SetRoundMode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Math.SetRoundMode) function.

Tested in Delphi 2006, Round and Ceil give the same result: 0.

Comment: *Ceil()* should always produce 0, indeed. *Floor()* should always produce -1. *Round()* is dependent on the rounding mode, although, AFAIK, only for values very near to `-0.5` (within one *ulp* -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place), which does not apply to the value given. It **should** always produce 0, even for `RoundMode = rmDown` (toward negative infinity).

Comment: The often referred site, http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html, says: `When used with the convert to integer operation, round toward - infinity causes the convert to become the floor function, while round toward + infinity is ceiling.`. So that explains why -1 is returned when `RoundMode = rmDown`.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking people to troubleshoot something for you. So I can offer the following ideas:

1. store the value of your division in a variable of type double.

   ```
   ...
   var
     val : Double;
   begin
    val := Expression1/expression2; // use single step in debugger to evaluate and store
    val := Round(val); // now step over this value.
    ...
   ```
2. Test using a literal:

   ```
   val := Round(0.006);
   val := Round(-0.006);
   ```

Observe consistent or inconsistent results, examine and post these results.  Remember that there are many things that can happen here:

A. What Types are involved and what significance/precision losses occur?

B. Do any integer overflow errors occur anywhere in your calculations that you haven't accounted for?

C. Is there anybody truncating any results that you haven't accounted for?

D. Exceptional circumstances; Someone asked in a comment about another function named Round()? A Cpu problem? Memory corruption? think creatively, you're a programmer. Turn on Debug-DCUs and single step through the code, in CPU view. Make sure you get to System.pas _ROUND. Use the debug expression evaluator and debug watch window to watch your variable values.  Figure it out.